# Plot network using ggnet2

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I have a network that I created by importing a gml file.
If I plot this network using `plot`, nodes have the correct label (string).
If I try to do the same thing using ggnet2, the labels become numbers.
Why?
This is my code:

```
   library(igraph)
   library(poweRlaw)
   library(sna)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(GGally)
   library(ergm)
   library(intergraph)

   net <- read.graph("./network.gml", format = c("gml"))
```

plot(net)
       netb <- asNetwork(net)
       ggnet2(netb, size = "degree", label = TRUE)

The results I get are:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data, it's most likely that `read.graph` is setting the vertex names to be numbers and that `plot` is grabbing the names from a different variable.  [The ggnet2 documentation](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/#node-labels) explains that the `label` variable can be set to the name of the vertex attribute that you wish to use.  Try changing `label = TRUE` to `label="<VertexName>"` where `<VertexName>`is the name of the vertex in `netb` that contains the labels.

Comment: Thank you, I solve replacing `label = TRUE` with `label = V(net)$label`.